# UIScrollView not scrolling after navigating back to view in ios7

Tags: uiscrollview, ios7

I have a project I was working on in XCode 4.whatever where the main view is a Netflix-style layout with a series of horizontally-scrolling scrollviews. The main scrollview may be scrolled vertically to see all of the horizontal ones. This is connected to a navigation controller so when an item is touched it performs a segue, whereupon the user can click a standard navigation bar back button.

This was working as expected with XCode 4.*, iOS 6.1. I have now upgraded to XCode 5 and iOS 7. The scrolling works fine upon initial load - the main vertical one and subview uiscrollviews. After navigating to an item and touching the back navigation bar button the main view won't scroll vertically. The subviews that are visible still scroll horizontally.

I am using a storyboard. The master view controller contains a Scroll View as the top item and a View with a couple subviews for the feature section at the top. The horizontal scrollviews are added programmatically.

The master view controller is a UIScrollViewDelegate and I have connected an IBOutlet from the main scrollview to my master view controller .h file.

That it works initially and then stops scrolling leads me to believe that the content size is being recalculated - and set equal to the frame size - after the navigation. However, I tried setting the content size within viewWillAppear to no avail. I did verify the routine was being called after navigation.

Any ideas on why the main scroll view loses its scrolling?

Comment: Finally saw that the contentSize was set to the frame size when I checked in viewDidLayoutSubviews. As a workaround I can reset the master scrollview contentSize in viewDidLayoutSubviews but the correct approach would be to stop auto layout from resizing the contentSize based solely on the elements that appear in the storyboard. Is there something I am not setting when adding elements programmatically?

Comment: Thanks, very good! Had the same problem except I am not using storyboard. Setting contentSize in viewDidLayoutSubviews works.

Comment: Same problem, ios 8 is working properly. But not in ios 7.
And I'm setting contentSize in viewDidLayoutSubviews method.
:(